# Kendo UI Angular2 Grid Columns Setup

Tags: grid, kendo-ui-angular2

Is there a way to setup columns like in kendo-ui grid manner?  Set up it from the code not from a html template.

Comment: For instance if each time I have different data sets with certain columns. I want to configure grid in run time on the client side, based on certain data sets.

Comment: Found, solution: <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="columns" let-column>